# Why I did not receive a notification that grace period of a bounty started?

Tags: support, bounties, notifications, global-inbox

From my past experience with bounties, you receive several notification as the bounty is closing to end: bounty expires in three days, bounty expires in one day, bounty expiring soon (this is announcement of the start of grace period). For example [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276143) has a screenshot where both notification that bounty starts in one day and bounty is expiring soon are displayed.

Recently I have offered a bounty on a question. As you can see below, the notification saying about start of the grace period ("bounty expiring soon") is not shown in my global inbox.

[image: screenshot of global inbox]

The question where I offered bounty is [this one](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/posts/5597/revisions).<sup>1</sup>

It is possible that I received notification and I have forgotten about it. (I remember several notifications in connection with this bounty, and I don't trust my memory enough to be absolutely sure whether the last one I saw was the "one day warning".) Still, even if I got a notification and somehow missed it, the fact that it is not displayed in the global inbox seems unusual.

To be fair, I have received some a notification also by email. However, this notification was sent some 7 hours before bounty expired. As this was during the night in my timezone, when I checked my email in the morning, it was already after grace period.

What I should learn from this is to follow more closely bounties that I offer, so that I do not forget to award them. (And maybe that I should get up earlier in the morning.) Still, I would like to ask:

1. Are there some situations which are [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) when the notification about grace period does not come into the inbox?
2. If in this case the notification is not shown as a result of some bug, could it be fixed?

<sup>1</sup>If it's better not to attract attention to a specific question, I can remove the link. However, I did not want to make life more difficult for people who might try to investigate this. After all, the question can be seen also in the screenshot - so people reading this can find the question even if I remove the link, it just takes a bit more effort.

Comment: We found some variance in whom got what/when for Bounty Notification, which was discussed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/282094 - there are warnings after the 24 hour warning.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the reference. The comments there are especially relevant. By the look of things, it looks like a case of inbox notification getting removed after bounty period ends.